# replace index.php with symlinks in direct subdirectrories

Tags: bash, debian

I have com across the Situation, that I need to replace all index.php files in direct subdirectories with a symlink to an index php in an repository.
This is the structure of my directory.

```
-
|__ _base
|   |__index.php
|
|__ foo.something
|   |__ index.php
|
|__ bar.something
    |__ index.php
```

now have to replace the `index.php` file in `foo.something` and `bar.something` with a symlink linking to the `index.php` in `_base`.

I however have to runn the command as a specific user on the server.
So i tried:

```
runuser -u username <<'EOF'
> for directory in ./*.something; do
>  echo $directory
>  ln -sf ../_base/index.php ./$directory/index.php
> done
> EOF
```

However that throws the error "no command found". I may put the commands in a script and execute it with superuser, still I am curious of I just missused runuser, or if there is an other solution as I am fairly new to working with bash.

Comment: Can you attach whole log? runuser might not be present on your system. If that's the case - try replacing runuser with su, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758235/how-to-execute-a-group-of-commands-as-another-user-in-bash

Comment: yeah, that was the problem! I am still failry new to the server wolrd! Thanks for helping out!